# How to create html elements dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
var elms = ["When?", "Why", "Where", ......];
```

I need to create the following elements

```
<html .. whatever> 

<div id="q1"> When?  </div>
<input type="text" id="a1"></input>

<div id="q2"> Why?  </div>
<input type="text" id="a2"></input>

<div id="q3"> Where?  </div>
<input type="text" id="a3"></input>

........
</html>
```

How can I do this ?

PS: My original page has only this array `var elms` and nothing else. I need to create all those divisions and inputs. I tried jquery, but messed up with the single and double quotes . . so I gave up.

Comment: you tagged this question as jQuery, have you actually gone to the jQuery site and read through the examples? Because this is very basic "using jquery" stuff and really not what you should be asking about on Stackoverflow. First try to find out on your own, then write code, then if that code doesn't work, we're here to help you figure out why (after you first tried to figure it out yourself)

Comment: Yes, I tried. But I messed up and it did not work

Comment: then you didn't try enough things, and/or or didn't read spend enough time reading the many examples the jquery site has on offer for you.

Comment: this isn't a `how to learn a programming language` site. Question shows a complete lack of research effort

Comment: Just to be clear. Do you mean that `elms[0]` would generate the entire HTML  `<div id="q1"> When?  </div><input type="text" id="a1"></input>`?

Comment: ***YES*** . this is the problem !

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek I think people are giving me `-1` because they think that I need to populate elements `q1`, `q2` ... But I need to create them. The original page is empty, I only have that array. How can I create these elements ?

Comment: @Buras, No. people are givin you -1 because of the `lack of effort or research`. If you hover the mouse above downvote symbol you'll see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var el;
 var idName;
 for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){
   idName = "q" + i;
   el = document.getElementById(idName);
   el.innerHTML = elms[i];
 }
```

Start your div ids with a index of `0` i.e `id="q0"` to make indexing easy

You can also do this with jquery:

```
 var el;
 var idName;
 for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){
   idName = "#q" + i;
   $(idName).html(elms[i]); 
   // items in the html( .. ) can be done only in 
   // newer versions of jquery (I think) correct me if im wrong
 }
```

***If they don't already exists:***

```
 var id;
 for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){
  id = "q" + i;
  $("#containerDiv").append(
   "<div id="+id+">"+elms[i]+"</div><input type=\"text\" id=\"a2\"></input>"
   );
 }
```

Comment: THank you. But this method ***populates*** the already existing elements `q1` ,  `q2` ..  I on the other hand need to create them. They are not there from the beginning

Comment: @Buras added it to the bottom

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[**Working jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8gfbkk8e/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Go" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
var nextbit, cnt=0;
var elms = ["When?", "Why", "Where", "How"];

$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $(this).hide(); //Hide the button
    elms.forEach(function(item){
        cnt++;
        nextbit = '<div id="q"'+cnt+'>' +item+ '</div>';
        nextbit +='<input type="text" id="a"'+cnt+'></input>';
        $('#result').append(nextbit);
    });
});
```